# An object key from an function parameter don't get the actual type

Tags: typescript, typeerror

I am facing a problem on typescript. The situation is, when I pass an object's key (union of object keys) as a function parameter then getting the value of the object using the key doesn't give me the correct type.

```
enum Name {
    house = 'house',
    building = 'building'
}

interface DataType {
    a: {id: string; name: string}[];
    b: {id: Name; name: string}[];
}

const data:DataType = {
    a: [{id: '1', name: 'abc'}],
    b: [{id: Name.house, name: Name.house}, {id: Name.building, name: 'def'}],
}
  
const getName = <T,>(key: keyof DataType, id: T) => {
    const value = data[key];

    return value.find(item => item.id === id)?.name || '';
    //------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------------
    //TypeError: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and 'T' have no overlap.
}

const res = getName('b', Name.house);

console.log(res);
```

In the code above the line

```
return value.find(item => item.id === id)?.name || '';
```

gives me a type error - ***This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and 'T' have no overlap.***

I've found a workaround by cast the `item.id` by `T`, like -

```
return value.find(item => (item.id as unknown as T) === id)?.name || '';
```

but is there any better solution?

Comment: why is the function generic? You could constrain `T` with `T extends string` but I guess it would be better to remove `T` since you don't use it anywhere else.

Comment: @TobiasS. I've updated my question, the `id` type should differ.

Comment: Ok, but you still have not answered why you need `id` to be generic? What is stopping you from writing `id: string`?

Comment: Tobias is correct, your function [does not need to be generic at all](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAcghhYUDeBYAUFLUAWB7MAZyQF4oByfI4cgGg2ygCMwBLAGwBNWQBzKMuRYdufchgC+GDDwAuwAE4AzOAGMkAETiy4AFQCeAByRpM2OAC4UrTlcKyFPXgG4oIBMDsOnEgNoBdZwZsJitkGyt4RFd3RC9HPj9AyWl0VTwQeyhObUstHQNjARRgrEsoX3DbCgBGOjcPK3I4JlVyCX96MyxQiqrIjwA6KmJaBrjYIZHgCTH+ycRB4S4nMdjPCk5gJXbOlLMMdMzZKF5gWSjSKAAKAGtgfSt7-TwlKHy9I2AxiKh7BP4AB8FsAAJTxJwCAB8JW6UCOWQAbnB2GArjkdL5nsl0KUoApzmAFCAoMjUcBBkoeJxrqx5NASDC6cAIIMbAISGQbKCAPyDdZQQHA8jkILoKS4tIZLIEwjFM4XDzXIT1cgAJnIoLFh2leHYFPYeF411lWowQA).

Comment: See the `DataType`, the `id` is not only `string` but also the `Name` enum. The could have many more variety. So decided to make it Generic.

Comment: you only need to make a function generic if you want to express relations between different parameters or if you want to use the generic type in the return type. Neither seems to be the case here. So a union should work fine.

Comment: That enum has string values, so `getName('b', Name.building);` is fine without the function being generic.

Comment: @JaredSmith in the real case the `id` could have many more type variety.

Comment: @SajeebAhamed no it can't. You're using it to index into an object, it can *only possibly* be `string | number | Symbol` and that looks like it was parsed from JSON, so probably not even `Symbol`.

Comment: @JaredSmith What if there are more **enum**s for the id?

Comment: Please add an example to your question where @JaredSmith's solution fails to do what you want.

Comment: @SajeebAhamed enums can only be strings or numbers. You can of course have a union of a bunch of different enums, but at what point should you just call a string a string? To second Alex Wayne, we need a motivating reproducible example in your question please.

Comment: @JaredSmith 's solution is fine, But the problem is if I need to write the union type for the `id` parameter and there are more enum types then I have to write it manually a long union. [Check this](https://cutt.ly/0LyDkUe)

Comment: Yeah, then just leave the enums out of the union and just use `string`

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround for that problem. The problem happens because the `key` param we declared is the union of the all properties.

But as this is a param of a function so the `const value = data[key]` cannot decide the exact type instead it takes the union of the all the `data[key]` types.

But the `id` is the Generic type, so the `id` takes the actual type but as the `value` variable doesn't infer the exact type so there makes some mismatch.

So, for solving this we need to declare the `id` type with the exact type matched with the `key` type.

The solution is -

```
const getName = <K extends keyof DataType, T extends DataType[K][number]['id']>(key: K, id: T) => {
    const value = data[key];

    return value.find((item) => item.id === id)?.name || '';
}
```

Now the `K` extends the `keyof DataType` and the `T` is the 'id' type for the specific key type `K`.

*Note: I just want to thank all the people who comments. This is okay to declare `string` as the type of the `id` as the `enum` extends `string`. This is valid but not a good solution.*

*Also this works if we declare the `id` as the union of the all possible types of the id. But it could overkill as there could be a huge variety of the types for the id in the `DataType`.*